# FlexCover 0.81 throws ServicesDepdendency Error no matter what

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, code-coverage, flexcover

I've used FlexCover quite a bit before so this is absolutely absurd to me. No matter what version of the flex sdk (3.0, 3.2, or 4) that I apply the appropriate patches too, I get the following error when trying to compile:

```
mxmlc Test.as

Error: flex/messaging/config/ServicesDependencies

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: flex/messaging/config/ServicesDependencies
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2395)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2519)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1406)
 at flex2.compiler.config.ConfigurationBuffer.loadCache(ConfigurationBuffer.java:516)
 at flex2.compiler.config.ConfigurationBuffer.loadCache(ConfigurationBuffer.java:560)
 at flex2.compiler.config.ConfigurationBuffer.<init>(ConfigurationBuffer.java:97)
 at flex2.compiler.config.ConfigurationBuffer.<init>(ConfigurationBuffer.java:81)
 at flex2.tools.Mxmlc.mxmlc(Mxmlc.java:81)
 at flex2.tools.Mxmlc.main(Mxmlc.java:55)
```

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening. One thing that is odd however (and I'm hoping is the source of my problem) is that I can NOT download the SDKs that are specifically suggested by the Flexcover documentation.

Is anyone experiencing this? Solutions? Thanks in advance.

**Solution:** Copying folders on Mac OS X does not merge them and so I was losing the original jar's that needed to stay there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this error when the lib directory from the Flex SDK is replaced with the lib directory provided by FlexCover in the corresponding sdk-modifications directory. In order for FlexCover to work the jar files in the lib subdirectory under sdk-modifications must be copied over the existing Flex SDK lib directory. The resulting Flex SDK lib directory should have 30 to 40 jar files in it when you are done.

The specific Flex SDK versions referenced in the FlexCover documentation are no longer available for download. I have successfully used FlexCover 0.81 with Flex SDK 3.2.0.3958 as downloaded from: 
http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+3